# What happens when offerings are forgotten to god?

Tags: gods, belief, rituals, goddess

Consider for example, when we are single, we might have visited n number of temples that could be Male God or Female God. And where ever we go, we might have prayed for blessings of a good life partner.

But once got married, how will we know whether to which god what did we pray for as its like almost forgotten. How will we even know, which God showered the blessing for marriage?

Comment: why does that even matter??????

Comment: Maybe sincerely tell thank you to all of them from the past visits ? & starting now with any temples you visit, you can click a photo with your phone & make a quick note on your phone too, where you went, what you prayed, things like that. And just say thanks genuinely from bottom of you heart 

Comment: @Ramachandra - it will matter